# The tangent to the curve $y=x^2+1$ at $(2,5)$ meets the normal to the curve at $(1, 2)$

Tags: derivatives

> Find the coordinates of the point where the tangent to the curve $y=x^2+1$ at the point $(2,5)$ meets the normal to the same curve at the point $(1,2).$

I tried to form 2 equations for each set of coordinates given, then solve then simultaneously to get the 'y and x' coordinates needed, however I didn't seem to get the answer right.

Answer (score 3):

- First, you need to find $f'(x)= 2x$.
- Then to evaluate the slope of the tangent line at the point $(2, 5)$,
  $m_1 = f'(2) = 4$. With slope $m_1=4$, and the point $(x_0, y_0) =
     (2, 5)$, use the slope-point form of an equation to obtain the
  equation of that tangent line.

$(y - y_0) = m_1(x - x_0)\tag{Point-Slope Equation Of Line}$

- To find the slope of the normal line at the point $(1, 2)$, first
  evaluate $f'(1) = m_2= 2$, the slope of the tangent line at that
  point. Then the slope of the normal line to the curve at that same
  point is $m_\perp = -\dfrac 1{m_2} = -\dfrac 12$. Using the slope of
  the normal line $m_\perp = -\dfrac 12$ and the point $(x_0, y_0) =
     (1, 2)$, use the slope point form of an equation to obtain the
  equation of the line normal to the curve at $(1, 2)$:
  $$(y - y_0) = m_\perp(x - x_0)$$
- Finally, find where the tangent line and the normal line intersect by
  setting the equations equal to one another. Solve for $x$, then find
  the corresponding $y$ value using the equation of either line.

Answer (score 0):

$y'(x) = 2x$

$y'(2) = 4$, so $4$ is the slope of the tangent at $(2,5)$.

You have a point and a slope, so you should be able to find the equation of a line.

Then $y'(1) =2$, so we invert *and negate* this to get the normal slope ($=-1/2$).

Point + slope --> equation.

Etc.

Comment: Of course! Time for more coffee :)

Comment: I ran into the same problem earlier this morning! Coffee to the rescue! ;-)